# This robot has a joint named "joint" which is not in the gazebo model

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, gazebo-ros-control

I am using the following method in https://answers.ros.org/question/223196/using-gazebo_ros_control-with-sdf-instead-of-urdf/ to actuate a 2D Gimbal model using the ROS Control Plugin. However, the following error pops up:

```
[ERROR] [1709058385.958866443]: This robot has a joint named "tilt_joint" which is not in the gazebo model.
[FATAL] [1709058385.959184504]: Could not initialize robot simulation interface
```

I am using the following urdf file to load robot_description

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="ros_gimbal_small_2d">



  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.2"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.001" ixz="0.001" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.001" izz="0.0001"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="base_col">
      <origin xyz="0.01  0.075 0.155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.05 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="base_main_viz">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/base_main.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name="base_arm_viz">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/base_arm.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="tilt_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.01"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.0001" ixz="0.001" iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.001" izz="0.00001"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="tilt_col">
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/tilt.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <collision name="depth_cam_collision">
      <origin xyz="0.02 0 0.016" rpy="3.14 0 1.57"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.073000 0.276000 0.072000"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="tilt_viz">
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/tilt.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name="depth_cam_visual">
      <origin xyz="0.02 0 0.016" rpy="3.14 0 1.57"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="model://kinect/meshes/kinect.dae" scale="1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="tilt_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-0.1" upper="3.14159265" effort="10.0" velocity="-1.0"/>
  </joint>
  <gazebo>
     <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/ros_gimbal_2D</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- transmission -->
  <transmission name="tilt_control_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
    <joint name="tilt_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
  </transmission>
</robot>
```

and a sdf file for launching the gazebo model

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='ros_gimbal_small_2d'>
    <pose>0 0 0.18 0 0 0</pose>

    <link name='base_link'>
       <inertial>
        <mass>0.2</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0001</ixx>
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0001</iyy>
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>

      <visual name='base_main_viz'>
        <geometry>
         <mesh>
           <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
           <uri>model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/base_main.dae</uri>
         </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/FlatBlack</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>

     <visual name='base_arm_viz'>
        <geometry>
         <mesh>
           <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
           <uri>model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/base_arm.dae</uri>
         </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/FlatBlack</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision name='base_col'>
        <pose>0.01 0.075 -0.025 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.1 0.05 0.15</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <link name='tilt_link'>
       <inertial>
        <mass>0.01</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.00001</ixx>
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.00001</iyy>
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>
          <izz>0.00001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
     <visual name='tilt_viz'>
        <pose>0 0 -0.005 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
         <mesh>
           <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
           <uri>model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/tilt.dae</uri>
         </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>

     <collision name='tilt_col'>
        <pose>0 0 -0.005 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
         <mesh>
           <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
           <uri>model://gimbal_small_2d/meshes/tilt.dae</uri>
         </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <collision name="depth_cam_collision">
      <pose>0.02 0 0.036 3.14 0 1.57</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.073000 0.276000 0.072000</size>
            <!-- <size>0 0 0</size> -->
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="depth_cam_visual">
      <pose>0.02 0 0.036 3.14 0 1.57</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://kinect/meshes/kinect.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
      <pose>0.02 0 0.036 3.14 0 1.57</pose>
        <update_rate>20</update_rate>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.047198</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>640</width>
            <height>480</height>
            <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.05</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
        </camera>
        <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
          <robotNamespace></robotNamespace>
          <baseline>0.2</baseline>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
            will control the frame rate. -->
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>camera_ir</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <depthImageTopicName>camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
          <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
          <pointCloudTopicName>camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
          <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
          <pointCloudCutoffMax>10.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
          <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
          <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
          <Cx>0</Cx>
          <Cy>0</Cy>
          <focalLength>0</focalLength>
          <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
      <!-- <visual name='camera_viz'>
        <pose>0 0 0.02 0 1.57 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.025</radius>
            <length>0.050</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>

         <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
        </material>
     </visual>

      <collision name='camera_col'>
        <pose>0 0 0.02 0 1.57 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.025</radius>
            <length>0.050</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
     </collision>

      <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 1.57</pose>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>2.0</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>640</width>
            <height>480</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.05</near>
            <far>15000</far>
          </clip>
        </camera>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <visualize>1</visualize>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <robotNamespace>roscam</robotNamespace>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>cam</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
          <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
          <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin> -->
      <!-- </sensor> -->

    </link>

    <joint name='tilt_joint' type='revolute'>
       <parent>base_link</parent>
       <child>tilt_link</child>

      <physics>
        <ode>
          <implicit_spring_damper>1</implicit_spring_damper>
        </ode>
      </physics>

      <axis>
        <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
        <dynamics>
          <damping>0.5</damping>
        </dynamics>
        <use_parent_model_frame>1</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <lower>-0.1</lower>
          <upper>3.14159265</upper>
          <effort>10</effort>
          <velocity>-1</velocity>
        </limit>
      </axis>
      <pose>0 0 0.02 0 0 0</pose>

      <inertial>
      <mass value="0" />
      </inertial>
    </joint>

    <!-- <plugin name="ros_gimbal_small_2d" filename="libGimbalSmall2dPlugin.so">
      <joint>tilt_joint</joint>
    </plugin>

    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher"
      filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
      <update_rate>20</update_rate>
      <joint_name>tilt_joint</joint_name>
    </plugin>

    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory"
      filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory.so">
      <update_rate>20</update_rate>
    </plugin> -->

  </model>
</sdf>
```

and the launch file to launch the Gazebo world with the gimbal model.

```
<launch>
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find ardupilot_gazebo)/worlds/multi_iris_with_roscam_runway.world"/>
    <!-- more default parameters can be changed here -->
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find ardupilot_gazebo)/models/ros_gimbal_small_2d/model.urdf" />

  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <rosparam file="$(find ardupilot_gazebo)/models/ros_gimbal_small_2d/config.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg ="controller_manager" type="spawner" ns="/ros_gimbal_2D" args="tilt_joint_position_controller joint_state_controller --shutdown-timeout 3"/>
    <!-- converts joint states to TF transforms -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <remap from="joint_state" to="/ros_gimbal_2D/joint_states" />
  </node>
```

I also have a config.yaml as such:

```
ros_gimbal_2D:
  joint_state_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 20

  tilt_joint_position_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: tilt_joint
      pid: {p: 1.0, i: 1.0, d: 0.0}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have included non-zero values for mass and inertia, as per what others have suggested, but the error persists.

---

Update: I created a URDF file for the IRIS drone with a gimbal camera, and it mitigated the abovementioned problem. The ROS Control Plugin can be used. However, I am unable to control the revolute joints on the gimbal. Is there another method for controlling revolute joints in Gazebo, preferably with a python script?